# Metropolis Hastings Proposal with Gradient and Hessian Information

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gradient, hessian

I need to sample a high-dimensional parameter vector from a distribution where the gradient, the Hessian and the inverse of the Hessian of the log-likelihood are very cheap to compute. Are there any well-established Metropolis-Hastings proposals that take into account both gradient and Hessian information? Is this even likely to improve efficiency significantly over a, e.g., MALA algorithm that is based only on gradient information?

Comment: HMC and other PDMP methods come to mind. Obviously, the devil is in the details (of the implementation).

Comment: There's a [Hessian-based MCMC algorithm by Herbst](https://economics.sas.upenn.edu/sites/default/files/filevault/event_papers/Econometrics10252010.pdf), but I'm not sure if and where there exists a software implementation.